# jsfiddle in chrome 16?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I made this simple [example](http://jsfiddle.net/mxzL2/5/), which doesn't work in Chrome 16 (latest), but does work in IE8. (I don't see any alert)

Does anybody know why isn't it working?

Comment: @delnan do you see alert ? ( I don't)

Comment: It's not about what I (or anyone else) sees or doesn't see. It's about what you expect and how Chrome diverts from it. The information that you don't see an `alert` helps - that's what people need to know. More debugging effort on your side would be better though (perhaps the error occurs during evaluation of `alert`'s argument).

Comment: Fixed That. I Had pop up blocker. thanks.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Your code is short and is executed in my browser exactly as I would expect. My browser is Chrome 16 also (exact version is `16.0.912.36 beta-m`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got probably blocked alerts (ticked "Do not show more popups from this page"). Try to refresh the page, and also try to visit [direct link](http://fiddle.jshell.net/mxzL2/5/show/)

Answer (score 0):

I am using latest Chrome and works for me

But either way, use jQuery's `.val()` method instead of `.attr('value')`.
[example](http://jsfiddle.net/mxzL2/7/)

Comment: I know that. but attr / prop works fine also with IE but in my chrome - it doesnt.

Comment: Fixed That. I Had pop up blocker. thanks.